# tableView not populating with data from array

Tags: ios, json, nsmutablearray, tableview, cell

I'm new to iOS development and Objective-C programming so forgive my "noobiness".

Here's the thing, I have a function that builds an array getting data from a JSON object.
I then have a second function, responsible for filling a tableView with data from contained in my array.

Problem is, the content of this array does not seem accessible from my tableView function, even though the array has been added to my header file and implemented in the main file.
The tableView remains empty...

Do you have any idea why that is?

Here are the functions, thanks a ton for your help!

1) Array building function:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
[self.responseData appendData:data];

    //Get data
    NSError *myError = nil;
    NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

    //Extract titles
    NSMutableArray *myResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *results = [res objectForKey:@"data"];

    for (NSDictionary *result in results) {
        NSString *title = [result objectForKey:@"colors"];
        NSLog(@"colors: %@", colors);
        [myResults addObject:colors];
    }

    self.colorNames = myResults;    
}
```

2) TableView filling function:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

//Set cell text
NSString *colorString = [self.colorNames objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
NSLog(@"%@",colorString);
cell.textLabel.text = colorString;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is the controller a TableViewController or is a ViewController with a TableView in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure you reload your table view data after receiving your json data? I would suggest a `[self.tableView reloadData];` at the end of your `connection:didReceiveData:` method. Otherwise the method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will be called only once after you view was loaded.

Cheers,
anka

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not reloading indeed. It might be stupid of me, but [self.tableView reloadData]; throws me an error as "tableView not found on object of type myViewController". How can I solve that? Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, i thought you are using a subclass of UITableViewController? If you are using a simple UIViewController you have to keep a reference/outlet to your table view within your main view. And then call the `reloadData` method on the instance of this table view.

Comment: I didn't have an outlet for the tableView, added one and put the reloading line as you suggested, worked like a charm, you're officially my hero. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must implement something more of the UITableViewDataSource protocol.
You have to supply at least a method **tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:** returning the actual number of rows your table have, before the **tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:** gets called to fill in the table with your data.

Best wishes

Bruno

Comment: Thanks Bruno, the solution suggested above actually worked fine and I already have a method getting the actual number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Is row a method of indexPath? I think it should be indexPath.row instead of [indexPath row]

Comment: You can call methods or access properties both ways in Objective C.